# dql - doctrine2 - symfony2 -> soundex

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

i can't find anything about dql and soundex.
Has anybody an idea how to use soundex with dql?

This is my example query:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT e FROM event e 
WHERE e.title SOUNDEX(:title)');
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement new [DQL function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) and then [register it in symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html).

Comment: The documentation is not really good. I need a Stringfunction example.  do you have any other sources. I can't find any good resources for this.

Comment: No, I don't have example, but I found this link, which has info your need - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language